# Why does this regex using *+ (possessive) not match

Tags: regex

I need to get the last match of [0-9.]* in a string like

```
one 1.234 three
some text 1.2321 xyz 1 5 1.234 and more text
some other text
```

but also need the text around it - even when there is no number like in the 3rd line

I wanted to use `^(.*)([0-9\.]*+)(.*)$` but it just matches the first (.*).

On the other hand `^(.*?)([0-9\.]*+)(.*?)$` just matches the last (.*?).

Why is that? I thought that it will try to satisfy all rules?

I know that I can exclude 0-9. from the last .* to get what I want, but I want to understand why the above isn't working although I used *+

Comment: What your intent behind using `*+` ?

Comment: And which regex engine are you using? `*+` may have entirely different meanings depending on the regex flavor.

Comment: PCRE engine. *+ is supposed to mean possessive. isn't it?

Comment: I tried to use *+ to make it possessive. I thought that this would mean that it will not give back (to other matches to the right) if it matches

Answer (score 3):

A possessive quantifier doesn't guarantee the longest possible match, it just prevents backtracking.  Neither of your regexes ever tries to backtrack, so the possessive quantifier has no effect.

With the first regex, the first `(.*)` consumes the whole string, then `([0-9.]*+)` and the second `(.*)` each consume nothing because there's nothing left to match.

With the second regex, the first `(.*?)` initially consumes nothing because it's reluctant.  Then `([0-9.]*+)` successfully matches some more nothing because it's still at the beginning of the string, which doesn't happen to start with a digit or a period.  Finally, the last `(.*?)` is forced to consume what's left (the whole string) despite being reluctant, because of the anchor (`$`) following it.

To solve your problem, we need to know more about the kind of input you can expect.  For example, if you know there will never be any digits or periods *after* the number you're looking for, you could use this:

```
^(.*?)(?:([0-9.]+)([^0-9.]*))?$
```

The key here is that the second capturing group, `([0-9.]+)`, uses a `+` instead of a `*`.  If there are no digits or periods in the string, the enclosing group, `(?:([0-9.]+)([^0-9.]*))?`, will match nothing, and the initial `(.*?)` will be forced to consume the whole string.  (The second and third groups will be empty.)

If there's more than one sequence of digits or periods in the string, the second group is guaranteed to match the last of them, because the third group, `([^0-9.]*)`, allows anything *but* those characters in the remainder of the string.

This is pretty weak, but it's the best I can do with the information you've supplied.  The point is, possessive quantifiers are brilliant when you can use them, but that doesn't happen nearly as often as you might expect.